# Can window focus with multiple displays follow the mouse on macOS?

Tags: macos, display, windows, mouse, dual-screen

I'm a new MacOS user and some things disturb me as it was more convenient on Windows.

One of them is the following: on a dual screen set up, I have to first click the second monitor for it to take the focus and only then do my actual work. On Windows, I was able to flawlessly switch from one screen to the other without the need to first focus it.

In other words, on Mac, when I'm on a screen and just move the mouse to the other and start to, say, select some text, my action is just ignored (as it's only the initial focus) and I have to start it again. On Windows it just select my text the first time.

It is quite annoying, as I often switch from one screen to the other (dev tools on one screen, debugging browser on the other).

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Mission control system preferences is the first place you’ll need to lock. Do you have one space for multiple monitors or does each monitor have its own space?

Comment: I have distinct spaces for each monitors, this way i can move from apps to apps on one screen while keeping the main app on the other screen. I didn't tried to use same spaces for every monitors as I have to log-out for this setting to take effect but I don't think this would fix the problem. BTW, I just realized this is the same behavior for apps on the same screen: we have to first focus the app an only then do the action... not really convenient.